Remove duplicate character from a string and keep only single occurrences using recursion
I tried removing multiple occurrences of characters from a string and keeping only one occurrence (first occurrence) using recursion. Occurrences could be consecutive or any way.
Note: I am not using any types of collections.
e.g. Input:- RAMAAM, Output:- RAM i.e It removed only the second and third occurrences of char 'A', second occurrence of 'M' and printed 'RAM'. I am getting stuck at calling the recursive function 'remove' with stack values as it is always being called with the same value 'A'. Please review once.
Here is the code which I tried.
class RecursionRemoveDuplicatesFromString {
    String newStr="";
    String subs = "";
    String remvDupl = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String removeDuplicates(String toSubs){
        //String toSubs = s;
        if(toSubs.length()==1){
            return toSubs;
        }
        
        if(i <= toSubs.length()-2){
            subs = toSubs.substring(i,i+1);
        }else{
            subs = toSubs.substring(i);
            return subs;
        }
        //String subs = i <= toSubs.length()-2 ? toSubs.substring(i,i+1) : return toSubs.substring(i,i+1);
        i++;
        System.out.println(subs);
        removeDuplicates(toSubs);
        //System.out.println(subs);
        remove(toSubs,subs);
        return newStr;
    }
    void remove(String s, String subs){
        if(s.length()==1){
            return;
        }
        while(j<s.length()){

            if(j <= s.length()-2){
                remvDupl = s.substring(j,j+1);
            }else{
                remvDupl = s.substring(j);
                //return remvDupl;
            }
            //String remvDupl = j < s.length()-2 ? s.substring(j,j+1) : "";
            if(remvDupl.equalsIgnoreCase(subs)){
                count += 1;
                //newStr += subs;
                if(count==1){
                    newStr += subs;
                }
            }
            j++;
    }
        //remove(s, remvDupl);
        count = 0;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "RAMA";
        
        RecursionRemoveDuplicatesFromString remvDupli = new RecursionRemoveDuplicatesFromString();
        System.out.println(remvDupli.removeDuplicates(s));
        
    }
}


Which occurrence do you want to keep? The first occurrence?

yes @Sweeper. It should be first occurrence.

Why are you not using Collection Objects? Is this a homework assignment, and using a Collection is not allowed by your teacher? Or is there another reason?

It is neither homework nor assignment.

"e.g. Input:- RAMA, Output:- RAM i.e It removed only second occurrence of char 'A' and printed 'RAM'." From the description, that is the expected behavior. How is the actual behavior of the program different than what is expected?

with this example i wanted to clarify the doubt that removal is not only for consecutive duplicate characters and, also, should keep the single occurrence of each character. @OldDogProgrammer

edited example description for more clarity.

Instead of creating multiple substrings of different sizes or relying on various indexes and counters to make sure that a letter is not repeated, you could simply employ a temporary StringBuilder.
Basically, the StringBuilder will be the collector of your unique letters, maintaining the original order, and check with the method indexOf() whether a letter is already contained or not. If the method returns -1, then the letter is not present in the builder and can be added; otherwise you can move on to the next letter.
Recursive Solution
The following solution also offers a complete recursive approach as you asked in the title of your question, unlike your remove(String, String) implementation.
public static String removeDuplicates(String str) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(str);
    return removeDuplicatesHelper(str, new StringBuilder(), 0);
}

private static String removeDuplicatesHelper(String str, StringBuilder builder, int i) {
    if (i == str.length()) {
        return builder.toString();
    }

    if (builder.indexOf(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))) < 0) {
        builder.append(str.charAt(i));
    }

    return removeDuplicatesHelper(str, builder, i + 1);
}

Iterative Solution
Here, I'm also attaching an iterative solution to prevent a StackOverflow for longer strings.
public static String removeDuplicates(String str) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(str);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (builder.indexOf(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))) < 0) {
            builder.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

Demo
Here is a demo with both solutions at OneCompiler.

@life888888 This is an intrinsic problem of recursion. Each call creates a new environment in the stack, which easily exhausts the memory when several calls occur, therefore causing a StackOverflow. An iterative approach will always be more efficient than a recursive one. I've proposed this solution only because OP specifically asked for it. I'll make sure to attach an iterative solution too.
